# How to receive only certain columns?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have this code which executes a sql query that should return just one column, `BIN_NUMBER`, since that is the only thing in the select statement. When I assign the result `emptybins` to the data grid however, it shows all columns originally in the BINS table. Is there a way to return just the column from the select statement so I don't have to manually hide the other columns?

I know I could do it if I built the query with LINQ but I am asking specifically about use with this function.
(dc is a DataContext from a LINQ to SQL class)

```
 var emptyBins = dc.ExecuteQuery<BIN>(
     @"SELECT BINS.BIN_NUMBER
       FROM BINS LEFT JOIN 
            INVENTORY_ACTIVE ON BINS.BIN_NUMBER = INVENTORY_ACTIVE.BIN_NUMBER
       WHERE (((BINS.BIN_TYPE)={0}) AND 
             ((INVENTORY_ACTIVE.BIN_NUMBER) Is Null))
       ORDER BY BINS.BIN_NUMBER;", "INVENTORY");

if (dc.DatabaseExists()) MainGrid.ItemsSource = emptyBins;
```

Comment: what is `dc`. Please elaborate about objects that you use for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data binding to an object uses the component-model for the type - in this case `BIN`. The fact that you've only *populated* one column is irrelevant - and the UI binding will neither know now care. If you are populating a partial object, either setup the UI manually rather than relying on automatic column generation - or create a type specific to your UI with *just* the fields that have values in them - and use `ExecuteQuery<ThatType>`. You *might* also be able to just use `ExecuteQuery<int>` (or whatever is the type).